# when i call a function to get one row result it will gives number of rows, why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

In here i wont to get only one row result as bill for TourId = 4, but it will gives there are number of rows with TourId = 4

```
--Functions
--(1)Tour Bill 
-- when enter a TourID it will genarate Tour Cost
--Multi statement table valued functions


CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Tour_Bill(@TourID int)
RETURNS @Bill TABLE 
(   TourID int,
    ItineraryID int,
    StartDate date,
    EndDate date,
    Duration int,
    Distance float,
    CustomerId varchar(30)
    Name varchar(180) NOT NULL,
    ContractNo varchar(12) NOT NULL,
    GuideID int,
    PaymentForGuide money,
    SpecielActivityCost money,
    VisitingPlaceTicketCost money,
    NumberOfPeople int,
    CostForMeal money,
    Accomadation varchar(100),
    TotalAccommodationCost money,
    TourPackegeCost money,
    TotalSpecielActivityCost money,
    TotalVisitingPlaceTicketCost money,
    GRAND_COST money
)  
AS 
BEGIN

INSERT INTO @Bill
         SELECT Tour.TourId,
                    Itinerary.ItineraryId,
                    StartDate,
                    EndDate,
                    DATEDIFF(day,StartDate,EndDate) AS Duration,
                    EstTravelDist,
                    CustomerId,
                    FirstName+' '+LastName AS FullName,
                    ContactNo,
                    Guide.IdNo,
                    CAST(500 * DATEDIFF(day,StartDate,EndDate) AS money) AS PaymentForGuide,
                    SpecialActivity.Cost AS SpecialActivityCost,
                    VisitingPlaces.Cost AS VisitingPlacesCost,
                    NumberOfPeople,
                    CAST(UnitPrice * DATEDIFF(day,StartDate,EndDate) * NumberOfPeople AS money) AS CostForMeal,
                    Location AS Accomadation,
                    CAST(UnitPrice * DATEDIFF(day,StartDate,EndDate) AS money) AS TotalAccommodationCost,
                    CAST(EstTravelDist * 40 AS money) AS TourPackegeCost, 
                    SpecialActivity.Cost * NumberOfPeople AS TotalSpecielActivityCost,
                    VisitingPlaces.Cost * NumberOfPeople AS TotalVisitingPlaceTicketCost,
                    CAST(EstTravelDist * 40 + SpecialActivity.Cost * NumberOfPeople + VisitingPlaces.Cost * NumberOfPeople + 500 * DATEDIFF(day,StartDate,EndDate) 
                    + UnitPrice * DATEDIFF(day,StartDate,EndDate) + UnitPrice * DATEDIFF(day,StartDate,EndDate) * NumberOfPeople AS money) AS GRAND_COST

    FROM (((((((((Itinerary
            INNER JOIN SpecialActivity ON
            Itinerary.ItineraryId = SpecialActivity.ItineraryId)
            INNER JOIN VisitingPlaces ON
            VisitingPlaces.ItineraryId = Itinerary.ItineraryId)
            INNER JOIN Tour ON
            Tour.TourId = Itinerary.TourId)
            INNER JOIN Guide ON
            Guide.TourId = Tour.TourId)
            INNER JOIN Vehicle ON
            Vehicle.TourId = Tour.TourId)
            INNER JOIN Accommodation ON
            Accommodation.TourId = Tour.TourId)
            INNER JOIN Participant ON
            Participant.TourId = Tour.TourId)
            INNER JOIN Person ON
            Person.IdNo = Guide.IdNo)
            INNER JOIN Contract ON
            Itinerary.ItineraryId = Contract.ItineraryId)
    WHERE Tour.TourId = 4
RETURN;
END

--How to Call the Function

SELECT * FROM dbo.Tour_Bill(101)

---These are the tables
create table Itinerary(
    ItineraryId int primary key identity,
    Description varchar(50)NOT NULL,
    TourId int,
    CONSTRAINT FK_Tour3 FOREIGN KEY (TourId) 
    REFERENCES Tour(TourId)  
);
--ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN Distance
ALTER TABLE Itinerary
ADD EstTravelDist float NOT NULL

create table SpecialActivity(
    Activity varchar(100),
    ItineraryId int NOT NULL,
    Dates date ,
    PRIMARY KEY(Activity,ItineraryId,Dates),     
    CONSTRAINT FK_Dates3 FOREIGN KEY (Dates,ItineraryId) 
    REFERENCES Dates(Dates,ItineraryId),        
);
---ADD COLUMN Cost
ALTER TABLE SpecialActivity
ADD Cost money NOT NULL

create table VisitingPlaces(
    Place varchar(100),
    ItineraryId int,
    Dates date ,    
    PRIMARY KEY(Place,ItineraryId,Dates),    
    CONSTRAINT FK_Dates5 FOREIGN KEY (Dates,ItineraryId)
    REFERENCES Dates(Dates,ItineraryId),        
);
---ADD COLUMN Cost
ALTER TABLE VisitingPlaces
ADD Cost money NOT NULL

create table Person(
    IdNo varchar(30) primary key,
    FirstName varchar(50) NOT NULL ,
    LastName varchar (100) NOT NULL,
    Gender char(1) NOT NULL,
    Nationality varchar  (50) NOT NULL,
    Email varchar(100) UNIQUE,
    Fax varchar(12) ,
    PostBox varchar (6) NOT NULL,
    Street varchar (60) NOT NULL, 
    City varchar (60) NOT NULL,
    Province varchar (60) NOT NULL,
    Country varchar(100) NOT NULL    
);

create table Tour(
    TourId int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    ResavationDate date NOT NULL,
    StartDate date NOT NULL,
    EndDate date NOT NULL,
    NumberOfPeople int NOT NULL,
    TourStatus varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    CustomerId varchar(30),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Person3 Foreign key (CustomerId)
     REFERENCES Person(IdNo) 
 );


create table Guide(
    IdNo VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY ,
    GovermentRegistrationNo varchar(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    YearsOfExperence int NOT NULL,
    TourId int,
    CONSTRAINT FK_Tour2 FOREIGN KEY (TourId) 
    REFERENCES Tour(TourId),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Person4 FOREIGN KEY (IdNo) 
    REFERENCES Guide(IdNo)
 );

create table Participant(
    ParticipantId varchar(30) primary key,
    Name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    ContactNo varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    PickupLocation varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    DropLocation varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    TourId int
    CONSTRAINT FK_Tour FOREIGN KEY (TourId) REFERENCES Tour(TourId) 
);

create table Accommodation(
    ContractNo int primary key ,
    Location varchar (50) NOT NULL,
    Class varchar(10),
    RentedRoomFacilitiesDescription varchar(1000),
    PvtRoomFacilitiesDescription varchar(1000),
    T1 bit,
    T2 bit,
    T3 bit,
    Dates date,
    ItineraryId int,
    TourId int,
    CONSTRAINT Fk_Dates FOREIGN KEY (Dates,ItineraryId) 
    REFERENCES Dates(Dates,ItineraryId),    
    CONSTRAINT FK_Tour4 FOREIGN KEY (TourId) 
    REFERENCES Tour(TourId),
);

create table Contract(
    ContractNo int primary key IDENTITY,
    PricingCriteria varchar(100),
    UnitPrice money,
    MiniPeople int,
    MaxPeople int,
    ContractType varchar(100),
    FinancialPenalty money,
    ItineraryId int NOT NULL,
    SupplierId int,
    CONSTRAINT FK_Itinerary2 FOREIGN KEY (ItineraryId)
    REFERENCES Itinerary(ItineraryId),
    CONSTRAINT FK_SupplierRegNo FOREIGN KEY (SupplierId) REFERENCES Supplier(SupplierRegNo)  
);
```

Comment: if there are several rows with the same Tour ID, then what is it you want? A sum total of some field for that tour. Or a count, maybe? Please be clear what your requirement is and preferably given an example of your desired output. If you have multiple rows with the same ID, then to get one row you need to either make it some kind of aggregate query, or make further restrictions in your where clause to guarantee that only one row can be returned.

Comment: There is no  multiple rows with the same ID and i wont to get total cost of each Tour @ADyson

Comment: Above you said "there are number of rows with TourId = 4". Hence my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Learn to write code that is readable. And then learn to debug your code. You have in your function:

```
WHERE Tour.TourId = 4
```

So your parameter currently serves no purpose other than to confuse anyone attempting to use the function. Obviously you need to replace the literal with your parameter. And for humanity's sake, remove all of those ridiculous parentheses in your FROM clause - they serve no purpose, have no effect, and only make your code more difficult to read and understand.